# Calculation of Standard Deviation of a column from a file through Tcl script using " expr " function

Tags: tcl

I want to know the Tcl script required for calculation of standard deviation of a column from a file using "expr" function. Suppose I have a input file named "input.dat" which contains the following data:

```
6 7
5 6
3 8
9 2
```

And I want to calculate the the standard deviation of "Column 2" only using the "expr" function of Tcl, so what will be the Tcl script for doing the calculation. I am very much new in this Tcl scripting, can anybody please help me with the Tcl script ?

Comment: If you need help starting with Tcl, use the [Tcl tutorial](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html). Otherwise, we expect you to ask a *specific* question *about your implementation*. Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @glenn jackman I can't understand from where to start. That's why asked for help.

Answer (score 0):

There's two key parts to this. The first is to get the column of data from the file, and the second is to calculate the standard deviation of that data. Since we've got easily identifiable parts, this is a *great* opportunity to make some procedures.

There's a few ways to write the column loader. Here's one:

```
proc LoadColumn {filename columnIndex} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set column {}
    while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
        set datum [lindex [split $line] $columnIndex]
        if {$datum != ""} {
            lappend column $datum
        }
    }
    close $f
    return $column
}
```

Now, calculating the standard deviation is simple enough now that we don't need to mix I/O in with it. The formula's basically just copied straight off Wikipedia, after all:

```
proc StandardDeviation {data} {
    set n [expr {double([llength $data])}]
    set sum [tcl::mathop::+ {*}$data]
    set mean [expr {$sum / $n}]
    set sum2 [tcl::mathop::+ {*}[lmap x $data {expr {($x - $mean) ** 2}}]]
    return [expr {sqrt($sum2 / ($n - 1))}]
}
```

(The only real advanced technique here is `[tcl::mathop::+ {*}…]` to calculate the sum of a list. You can use a `foreach` and `expr` instead, but it takes more code.)

Then we can plug the pieces together:

```
set file "myfile.dat"
set column [LoadColumn $file 1];  # Column indices count from zero
set sd [StandardDeviation $column]
puts "The standard deviation is $sd"
```

Splitting problems up is vital to making programs that you can understand.